# Plot function while ranging some of the variables

Tags: plotting

So I have the function $f(a,b,c) =(a-b) - c$ with some constants in there as well. However, I want to make a 2d plot along $c$ while varying $a$ and $b$. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: If your equation is multivalued (i.e. for some fixed $a,b$ there are multiple $c$'s solving it), you could use a `ContourPlot3D` with $a,b,c$ all varying.  Mathematica might be able to `Solve` for $c$ (in which case a simple `ContourPlot` would do).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, b_, c_] := (a - b) - c

{min, max} = #[{f[a, b, c], 0 < a < 10, 0 < b < 10, 0 < c < 10}, 
  {a, b, c}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {-20, 10} *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[a, b, c], {c, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {min, max}],
 {{a, 5}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 5}, 0, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]